# Adding images from parse to int[]

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

I have a custom listview.

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

int[] images = {};
String[] names = {};



public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] names, int[] images) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_row, names);

    this.images = images;
    this.names = names;

}

public class ViewHolder {

    TextView username;
    ImageView imageView2;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

    View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);

    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    holder.username = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.username);
    holder.imageView2 = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    holder.imageView2.setImageResource(images[position]);
    holder.username.setText(names[position]);

    return customView;

}
```

}

I am trying to download images from parse and have the displayed in a listview.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Profile");

    query.whereEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {

                if (list.size() > 0) {

                    for (ParseObject object : list) {

                        final ParseFile file = (ParseFile) object.get("profilePicture");

                        file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {

                                //it gets to here

                                if (e == null) {

                                    Log.i("AppInfo", "I am here");

                                    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);



                                    Log.i("AppInfo", "I am here2");

                                    Log.i("AppInfo", "I am here3");






                                } else {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        });

                    }

                }

            }

        }
    });
```

I am unable to download the images and display them on the custom listview. The problem I am having is that the images from parse have to be stored in an int[], otherwise "holder.imageView2.setImageResource(images[position]);" will never work, as it needs to be an int[] to get the position. int[] does work as I have tested it with images stored on the phone (not downloaded from parse and stored, pre-stored before the app launches). If there is a better method of creating custom listviews with images, please inform me.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it wrong. `imageView2.setImageResource(int)` is doing something else. All files in your resource-folder are indexed and stored as `int` index, that can be referenced as `R.drawable.name_of_the_local_image`. So with that function you can only load local files. What you need is this:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
holder.imageView2.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

**EDIT**:
I found some code samples from Parse, maybe you should use their UI-Classes, like `ParseImageView` or `ParseQueryAdapter`. `ParseImageView`:

```
ParseFile parseFile = parseObject.getParseFile("image");
ParseImageView parseImageView = (ParseImageView)findViewById(R.id.parse_image_view);
imageView.setParseFile(paresFile);
imageView.loadInBackground();
```

for your query try to use `ParseUser` as objectType: `public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e)`

Comment: Thank you. That worked. but now I have another problem. One that has never surfaced since I haven't gotten that far in the code. `remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.jordon.newcustomlistview/cache/com.parse/files/http:/my_ipadres‌​s/parse/files/testid/7855bc4b6bef31f98bf61c9c024b8698_image.png.tmp `there is an image there and it was uploaded from an app I made.  This happens when I try to retrieve a file (that is an image) from parse.

Comment: can you show the code, that produce the error? Your path seems to be wrong, you probably messed up local-directory and url

Comment: `parseFileArrayList.get(position).getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                                    if (e == null) {
                                        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

                                        holder.imageView2.setImageBitmap(image);` the getDataInBackground never finishes because of the error I'm getting

Comment: I figured it out. But the solution created another problem. The parse url I am using is https. If I switch it to the old url I used that was http, it works and I don't get any errors. I need to use https for security. Any idea why it does that?

Comment: just a guess, but you have "http:/" in the file-path, that's why it works with "http"-urls, you should change it somewhere in code this part to "https" and maybe it will work, but hard to say without seeing more code

Comment: where do you actually write the file to local storage?

Comment: I don't save the file to the phone if that's what you mean. The file (image) is just being displayed in a listview. So once they navigate to a different activity, the files (images) are gone until they navigate back to the listview. I don't specifically write the file path. I retrieve the file name from parse and then the code determines the path required to load the file (image).

Comment: I updated the answer. I found some code samples on parse.com and they have own `Adapter` and `ImageView`-classes, maybe you should use them

Comment: I don't understand how this would solve my problem. My application works as long as I connect to parse using a http url. https is what I have to use and it won't work with that.

Comment: maybe you should make a new question, this has nothing to do with the original question